# Deriving Fokker-Planck equation for a microswimmer

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, random-walk

I am learning about Stochastic processes and an exercise that I am trying to complete asks me to find the Fokker-Planck equation for the position of a microswimmer in 2D that follows the following Langevin equations:

$$\mathbf{v}(t)=\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}}{\mathrm{d}t}=v\mathbf{n}(t)+\mathbf{u}(t),\quad \frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t}=\omega +\beta(t)$$

Where $\mathbf{n}(t) = (\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$ and $\mathbf{u}(t)$ and $\beta(t)$ are Gaussian white noise that have correlations:

$$\langle \beta(t)\rangle = 0,\quad \langle \beta(t)\beta(t^{\prime})\rangle = 2D_{r}\delta(t-t^{\prime}) \\ \langle u_{i}(t)\rangle = 0,\quad \langle u_{i}(t)u_{j}(t^{\prime})\rangle = 2D\delta_{ij}\delta(t-t^{\prime})$$

I have found the moments:

$$\langle \mathbf{v}(t)-\mathbf{v}(0)\rangle = 4D\delta(t) + v^{2}\cos(\omega t)\exp\left(-D_{r}t\right) \\
\langle [\mathbf{r}(t)-\mathbf{r}(0)]^{2}\rangle = 4Dt + \frac{2v^{2}D_{r}t}{D_{r}^{2}+\omega^{2}}+\frac{2v^{2}(\omega^{2} - D_{r}^{2})}{(D_{r}^{2} + \omega^{2})^{2}}+\frac{2v^{2}e^{-D_{r}t}}{(D_{r}^{2} + \omega^{2})^{2}}\left[(D_{r}^{2}-\omega^{2})\cos(\omega t) - 2\omega D_{r}\sin(\omega t)\right]$$

To derive the Fokker-Planck equation, I then use that:

$$\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{x},t) = \langle\delta^{(2)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{r}(t))\rangle$$

Taylor expanding $\delta^{(2)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{r}(t+\Delta t))$ gives:

$$\delta^{(2)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{r}(t+\Delta t))=\delta^{(2)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{r}(t))-\Delta r_{i}\partial_{i}\delta^{(2)}(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{r}(t)) + \Delta r_{i}\Delta r_{j}\partial_{i}\partial_{j}\delta^{(2)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{r}(t))$$

So we have:

$$\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{x},t+\Delta t) - \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{x},t) = -\Delta r_{i}\partial_{i}\delta^{(2)}(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{r}(t)) + \Delta r_{i}\Delta r_{j}\partial_{i}\partial_{j}\delta^{(2)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{r}(t))$$

However, I'm not entirely sure how to proceed from here?

Comment: You are almost done. Just average the penultimate equation and take into account that you have a Gaussian distribution.

Comment: @Jon So will I end up with something like: $$\partial_{t}\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{x},t) = \frac{1}{2}\langle \mathbf{r}^{2}\rangle\nabla^{2}\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{x},t)$$ Or have I misunderstood what you mean? And then can I let $t \gg 0$ to simplify $\langle \mathbf{r}^{2}\rangle$ to get: $$\partial_{t}\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{x},t) = \frac{1}{2}\left(4D + \frac{2v^{2}D_{r}}{D_{r}^{2} + \omega^{2}}\right)t\nabla^{2}\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{x},t)$$

Comment: That's right. That is a Fokker-Planck equation. You have already computed the averages. Just include velocity.

Comment: @Jon I'm probably being thick, but I'm not sure what you mean by including velocity? I don't see any velocity terms in my Taylor expansion of $\delta^{(2)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{r}(t+\Delta t))$?

Comment: You have two independent stochastic processes for ${\bf v}$ and ${\bf r}$. So, you should consider ${\cal P}({\bf x},{\bf u},t)=\langle\delta^2({\bf x}-{\bf r}(t))\rangle\langle\delta^2({\bf u}-{\bf v}(t))\rangle$ instead.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, aren't $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{r}$ intrinsically related through $\partial_{t}\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{v}$? In which case, whilst $\mathbf{v}$ or $\mathbf{r}$ on their own are Markov processes, given history of either, the other can be fully deduced? Again, apologies for any confusion, I am new to this!

Comment: You are right. Sorry, confusion was mine. I have seen two stochastic processes involved. I meant that at your equation is just missing a drift term. The procedure to obtain a Fokker-Planck equation is just this.